# How to turn comma seperated rows of a table into multiple columns

Tags: r, split, multiple-columns

I have a table similar to the following, where there is only one column and the cells contain data that are seperated with a comma.

```
1 height,weight

2 180,85

3 165,62

4 170,73
```

I want to split them into multiple columns by comma in order to get the following result

```
    height   weight

1   180       85

2   165       62

3   170       73
```

However, `str_split_fixed(x$type, ",", 2)` command that has been proposed on a similar topic doesn't seem to work for my case.

Thank you so much in advance for your answers.

Comment: How did you get this data into R in the first place? Was it just not correctly imported the first time?

Comment: When you say `str_split` "doesn't work", what do you mean? Are there errors? warnings? Incorrect output?

Comment: Looks like you have a CSV in a single column. `read.table(text = your_data[[1]], sep = ",", header = T)` should work. But as MrFlick suggests, the best place to fix this is probably upstream when the data was read into R.

Comment: So add `sep = ","` to your `read.table` command.